# Installing handlebar

Tags: handlebars

I've bought a 25.4 mm bullhorn for my fuji feather 2013, and I tried to install it.Then I've realized that my quill stem is for 26 mm handlebar.
Are there any ways to install 25.4 mm handlebar into 26 mm quill stem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can buy 0.3mm stainless steel sheets for shimming, but as bullhorns are quite heavily loaded (your weight will create more torsion at the clamp than on an equivalent drop bar), I'd return or re-sell the bar, or replace the stem.

Comment: Why would bullhorns experience any more torsion force than equivalent drops, assuming the rider uses the hoods?

Comment: I wasn't making that assumption ;-) I was comparing them with drop bars held in the curve. A correctly sized low-pro frame fitted with bullhorns has the same contact point relationship as a correctly sized track frame with drops. The difference is that with drops the vector of the force through the hands is far closer to the plane through the hands and the stem clamp.

Comment: This reply needs images!

Comment: Please, no selfies!!

Comment: Are we so low in your estimation...? Labelled engineer's diagrams of course!

Comment: Exchange for a fitting bar. IMO it's too dangerous to mess with shims on a handle-bar!

Comment: Meh, I've seen plenty of hideous shimmed hack jobs over the years that looked awful but worked just fine. If you can shim a seatpost, then handlebars are even easier. Shim away!